# How virtual thread is parking?

Tags: java, jvm, project-loom, virtual-threads

How are virtual threads parked in Project Loom, specifically in scenarios other than `LockSupport.park()`? I've noticed that `LockSupport.park()` is used in `FutureTask` and `CompletableFuture`, but what about situations involving **I/O operations**? I came across this code snippet (link: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/hotspot/cpu/aarch64/sharedRuntime_aarch64.cpp#L1174-L1226) involving continuation yield intrinsic, but I'm unclear about where this intrinsic fits into the picture, as I understand intrinsics are typically used for performance optimization. Additionally, I'm curious about `ObjectMonitor`, which use pthread_mutex with cond (link: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/f61499c73fe03e2e3680d7f58a84183364c5c5ac/src/hotspot/share/runtime/objectMonitor.cpp#L757), how does it work with `virtual thread` where `pthread` doesn't exist?

Comment: Intrinsics are not only used for performance optimizations, they are also used for operations not expressible with ordinary code in the first place. But what do you hope to gain from looking at such low level code? The difference between scenarios involving `park` and I/O are not handled at such a place. Releasing the carrier thread inside a `synchronized` block is currently not supported, so that should answer your second question.

Comment: @Holger, I'm currently exploring the mechanism by which compilers handle thread parking, specifically in the context of VirtualThread in Java (similar to how Golang handles goroutine suspension at compiler-determined points). It seems that in Project Loom, the responsibility for parking threads lies with the standard library, and the compiler does not play an active role in this process. Could you provide any insights or clarification on this topic?

Comment: If by “compiler” you mean javac (or source to bytecode compiler in general), then yes, it’s not involved. The standard library is responsible for parking and since the standard library also contains (most of) the blocking I/O operations, it’s also the standard library’s responsibility to replace those calls with async calls under the hood and park the virtual thread until completion.

Comment: @Holger, it appears that Virtual Threads don't employ a preemptive model. Does this mean it's possible to effectively 'pin' a virtual thread as long as it doesn't perform any I/O operations?"

Comment: You should not rely on this idea. Compare with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75767787/2711488)